# how to extract payload from action directly in the returned object

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am using `Redux`. In the reducer below I get an error if I use:

```
return({...state, action.payload});
```

instead:

```
const add= (stateaction) => {
  switch (action.type) {       
    case "ADD":
    const {payload} = action;///  <=
    return({...state, payload}); // <= instead of thes two lines
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I remember we could do that with adding brackets, something like:

```
return({...state, [action.payload]});
```

but cannot get it right.

Comment: post the error that you are getting

Comment: If your payload is also an object, you will need to spread its contents in the same way you spread your previous state: `return ({ ...state, ...payload });`. Otherwise, the ES6 shorthand will create a key in the resulting object called `payload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also spread it, if you need the contents of the payload in your state:

```
const add = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {       
    case "ADD":
      return {...state, ...action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

If the state is an array, you can use [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to add items to it:

```
const add = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {       
    case "ADD":
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I need to have that `action.payload` there and `...action.payload' doesn't work, i am 100% sure there was a trick to inject it directly into the object via adding brackets `[]`

Comment: You need the payload contents or the property payload? What should be the end result (the state object)?

Comment: I know how to get it work, my question is about that trick with `[]` i need to rememebr that

Comment: You'll tell give an example of a dispatched action with a real payload, and the end state that should be returned from the reducer, and I'll show you the trick with the brackets afterwards. Deal?

Comment: return from reducer is `[{name: "blabla", address: "asdsad", rate: 0, lld: ""}
{name: "kilkeni", address: "close to me :)", rate: 4.5, lld: ""}]`    paylaod is: `{name: "kilkeni", address: "close to me :)", rate: 4.5, lld: ""}`

Comment: See updated answer. There are two bracket tricks - array spread to add an item, and return a new array, and computed properties. Since your state is an array, I believe that you need the spread.